# NPM run serve VueJS very slow

Tags: vue.js, performance, npm

I'm running a project (quite big) with VueJS and npm. Every time I run npm run serve it takes 4/5 minutes, then when I make changes it's very quick to make the differential compile but every 5/6 differential compiles it slows down again for one run and then is fast again (by fast I mean under 10 seconds).
I thought different kind of changes made it slow or fast so I did and undid the same piece of code 5/6 times in a row and the differential compile still slowed down at one point.
I'm running eslint for vue so it's not broken divs or something similar (as suggested in other posts, I have searched the internet for this with no help to my case). I also tried productionSourceMap: false with no luck.
Any ideas?
Let me know if more info is needed and I will integrate it.

Thanks,
James

Comment: What bundle tool are you using? Vue-cli? Pure webpack? Vite? How slow is it when you hit than slow update? Is it rebundling the entire app or is it still hot-reload?

Comment: There's no simple explanation for that, it's very specific to your setup. Did you try it on other machines with the same result? A possible explanation is RAM

Comment: other machines have the same result. I'm using webpack and a slow hot-reload is 3/4 minutes compared to a quick 5/10 seconds.

Comment: actually I'm using webpack in vue-cli. I've noticed running some more tests that the problem seems to be when making changes to scss files it seems to be rebuilding the whole app instead of hot-reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install -D fibers
```

Solved it for me, atleast for the hotloads which was what the main problem was.